# Root and sign of a complicated bivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Given two natural numbers $p$ and $i$, such that $0 < i \leqslant 2^p$, let
$$
\Phi(p,i) := \frac{1}{2^p+1}
+ \frac{1}{(i+1)^2} - \frac{1}{2^p}\lg\left(\frac{2^p}{i}+1\right),
$$
where $\lg x$ is the binary logarithm. With the help of a Computer Algebra System, it *seems* that

- If $0 \leqslant p \leqslant 3$, then $\Phi(p,i) < 0$.
- If $4 \leqslant p$, there exists $i_p$ such that $\Phi(p,i_p) = 0$
  and $\Phi(p,i) > 0$ for $1 \leqslant i < i_p$,
  and $\Phi(p,i) < 0$ for $i_p < i \leqslant 2^p$.

> How can I prove this?

Just in case, the partial derivative with respect to $i$ is:
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial i}(p,i) = \frac{1}{i(2^p+i)\ln 2} - \frac{2}{(i+1)^3},
$$
where $\ln x$ is the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter Mueller at MathOverflow solved the problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108816/root-and-sign-of-a-complicated-bivariate-function